# Correct webform url for navigation

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm having problems with the navigation which is within my template.master file.

I have a menu with links to my own pages within the site.
For the default.aspx with template.master the link to about.aspx works fine as all files are in the same folder. So far so good. href="about.aspx"

If I try and use the same template.master for a file located in /categories/browse.aspx
the memu links no longer work as they are pointing at the current folder of /categories/
Is there a way of writing the href so that it always works. I thought that absolute reference might work like this.
href="/about.aspx"

This seems to work on the the live website domain run local it breaks as
    (/about.aspx) becomes the url when it should be 
    (/ast_web/about.aspx)

I seem to have the following options

1. Remove the local ast_web (projectname) from the path when developing. Is this possible?
2. create all the urls dynamically with a function.
3. Use some form of addressing that I dont know about. what does ~/ do?
4. Use a separate template.master for webforms in a sub folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned `href` attribute I would assume you are using plain `a` tags for your links in menu. As described in [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) MSDN article you can use `~` which is web application root operator.

This operator could be used in server controls such as `Hyperlink`. Just set `NavigateUrl` equal to `~/about.aspx` and it should solve your issue. And `Hyperlink` control still renders the same `a` tag so I see no problems from resulting HTML markup side.